# left join table filtering and grouping

Tags: python, postgresql, ponyorm

I'd like to do a query like this:

```
select t1.label, count(t2.id) 
from t1 left join t2 
    on t1.id = t2.fk [and t2.field_1 = 'x' and ...] 
[where t1.field_a =  'y' and ...] 
group by t1.label;
```

My initial attempt was to do

```
sub_query = pony.orm.select(x for x in t2)
apply_sub_filter(sub_query, ...)
query = pony.orm.select((y.label, pony.orm.count(sub_query)) for y in t1)
apply_filter(query, ...)
```

That doesn't work (not even when removing the filters)

According to the 4th example in [this doc](https://docs.ponyorm.org/queries.html#) reusing queries is supported, so I assumed the **count** is what throw is off here.

It works when putting it all in one select()

```
pony.orm.select(y.label, pony.orm.count(x for x in t2 if x.fk == y.id [and ...]) for x in t1 [if ....])
```

this works as expected but it **hardcodes both set of filters, and I need them to be dynamic**.

I could write every possible combination of filter and choose which query to run based on the filter I get at runtime, but I think everyone will agree it defeats the purpose of using an ORM

*As a side note: The documentation states that running this kind of subqueries (like the last example) would be optimised by ponyorm as a left join, but when I observe what queries run in database, there is no left join, only subqueries, which is likely going to be very slow on larger datasets.*

How can I make this works ? I will also need to support pagination later on.

Any chance to optimise this to have ponyorm use *left join* instead of *subqueries* ?